# TimeoutException in System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm new to Reactive Extensions. While running my application in Visual Studio, I get the following exception which I cannot reproduce reliably it but always happens given enough time:

> System.TimeoutException was unhandled
>
> Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll
>
> Additional information: The operation has timed out.

The Break Mode tab shows the message:

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show
> because all threads were executing external code (typically system or
> framework code).

I have no clue as to where to look for the problem, except that it might have to do with Reactive Extensions. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: You really need to show us your code.

Comment: I had no idea as to where the issue was coming from. I was using Rx in tens of places, so I would not know which piece of code to post. I managed to track down the problem, to an erroneous usage of a Timeout operator that was not supposed to be there. Unfortunately, there was no OnError handler for it either. I do not use test frameworks and got punished for it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The second message (Break Mode) is something that always gets shown in Visual Studio - that's the definition of "Break Mode" - In any application that you debug with VS you can "break" the app (using the "Pause" button, for example) - This allows you to better debug and understand the state of your parameters, objects and callstacks. The code is not showing up since you're using external code that your have no sources for.

Regarding the first exception, as you said, the platform services have a timeout. After a determined period of time something has not happened, the application will throw this timeout saying that the expected operation didn't complete in the amount of time that was specified for it. I can't tell you really why this is happening on your specific machine, but you should check if the extension requires something to initialize that you might not be providing it.

Comment: It was not an issue of initialization. It was an issue of using the Timeout operator the wrong way. Please see my comment above. Thanks for the help.